# Delete data from wordpress when deleted from remote xml file

Tags: json, xml, wordpress, woocommerce

I m using wp_remote_get to work with XML in WordPress. I want to delete the data from my wordpress site every 12 hours when deleted from remote xml file.

Answer (score 0):

you will directly create a cron job in cpanel and set its time. it will automatically clear the code after a particular time interval.

Comment: Im using following code: $response = wp_remote_get('http://dita.q44.nl/data/Itemdata.xml');
        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($body);

        /*         * */
        $json = json_encode($xml);
        $item_json = json_decode($json, TRUE);  If i add cron job in cpanel, it will delete data from every 12 hour or if i delete from xml url

Comment: add me on skype : harryr891

Comment: I sent you request @haninder